# .ipaにAlamofireが無いと言われてアプリが起動しません。

Tags: swift, cocoapods

Xcode 6.4でcocoaPodsを利用して、アプリを作りましたが、実機にて開発、動作検証までできているのですが、.ipaを作成してアプリをダウンロード、そして起動させるとその場でアプリが落ちます。
ログを見るとcocoaPodsを利用してAlamofireを使用してたのですが、それが無いとエラーが吐かれました。

ipaを作成する時のarchiveの設定が悪いのかcocoaPodsの設定が悪いのか、よく分かりません。

どなたかお分かりになるでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 因みにですが、ipaファイルはターミナルからコマンド叩いて出力されたりしていますか？その際に、workspaceではなくxcodeprojに対してarchiveしてないか気になりました。

Comment: .ipaファイルはworkspaceをXcodeで開いて　Product > Archiveで作成しています。

Comment: なるほど。ipa出力はDebugとReleaseのどちらで実施されていますか？
(恐らく、動作検証ではDebugでされていると思うのですが、ArchiveはReleaseになっているかもしれません。その場合、設定に違いがあるかもしれません。)
また、実際のエラーログを載せて頂くことは可能でしょうか？

Comment: Dyld Error Message:
Dyld Message: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/31D5EE28-
C5BA-449A-8ECA-94D6032A0B99/salestool.app/salestool
  Reason: image not found
  Dyld Version: 370.1

Binary Images:
0x100020000 - 0x10005ffff salestool arm64  <
31ef69a9f04537ce8c4d42c1e369dbee> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/
Application/31D5EE28-C5BA-449A-8ECA-94D6032A0B99/salestool.app/salestool
0x120034000 - 0x12005ffff dyld arm64  <d4078742b8573661b9fe465518caed3c>
/usr/lib/dyld

Comment: 上記のようなエラーとなります。
> ipa出力はDebugとReleaseのどちらで実施されていますか？ 
こちらですがXcodeのどの箇所で設定できるのでしょうか?ipa出力はすべてReleaseになると思っておりましたので。。。